# What does "Hey! quit shoving!" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Came across:

> He rushed past her like a football tackle, bumping her. "Hey, quit shoving!" she said, closing the door behind them. 
>   Source: [a James Thurber short tale](http://jameshilston.com/pages/reading/catbird_seat.htm)

I would like to know what it means generally and in this context.

In the text the women says this to the man who has passed her swiftly. It happened quickly and something like the following picture has not happened.I have checked dictionaries before posting this question. What makes a question is that we usually tell someone "quit doing something" when they are doing it not just once in a moment.

Found this nice pic on it:

[image]

Comment: **quit**:[informal , chiefly North American Stop or discontinue {an action or activity}](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/quit) **shove**:[To push rudely or roughly](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/shove). You've even posted an illustrative *picture!* I'm having trouble seeing how this can be anything other than General Reference, even for ELL. Convince me otherwise.

Comment: @FumbleFingers In the text the women says this to the man who has passed her swiftly. It happened quickly and something like the pic has not happened. This rose my question.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Perhaps some questions might seem silly to you since you are a native English-speaker. However they are not as easy or clear for me to understand as for you.

Comment: @Juya, I believe that you might have skipped the part *tackle* and *bumping* in *"He rushed past her like a football tackle, bumping her."* This means that he did ran into her, hard enough. Roughly, her *Hey, quit shoving!* means *Don't push (hit) me hard like that!*

Comment: @Juya: I'm sorry, but that doesn't convince me. You should not expect to understand a two word imperative such as "quit shoving" by simply googling for a picture, comparing it to your cited text, and giving up. Both words are easily found in the dictionary, and as Damkerng points out, if you'd read the preceding words in the sentence, there should be no problem interpreting what those dictionary definitions should have suggested to you - *"Hey! **Stop pushing [me] roughly**!"*

Comment: ...If that level of comprehension is too difficult for you, you should definitely not be using Thurber as a learning aid. His writing style in general is far more complex than this trivial example would suggest.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It is OK. I see his writing is difficult for me but I truly thirst for understanding this text completely. Thanks for your advice and help. BTW, I had checked dictionaries before posting this question. What made a question is that we usually tell someone "quit doing something" when they are doing it not just once in a moment. Of course I think I have not heard this kind of usage up to the time reading this story.

Comment: oic. I will post an answer then.

Comment: @Juya Your comments explain some confusion that is not in your question. Can you edit your question to make it more specific?

Comment: @nxx Just did what you kindly suggested. Hope my Q is better now

Comment: @Juya, It is much clearer now. FumbleFingers' answer is already spot-on, though, I think!

Comment: @Juya: I just noticed your edit. I'm sorry I didn't think through the implications of your comment earlier, but nxx is quite right to say such clarification should be *in the question text*. Anyway - now you've fixed the question so well, I've reversed my (admittedly rather harsh) downvote to an upvote. It is a very fair question.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: It is OK. Truly thx for your help:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per comments, [**quit**:](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/quit) *informal , chiefly North American - stop or discontinue (an action or activity)*, and [**shove**:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/shove) *push rudely or roughly,* giving *"Hey! **Stop pushing [me] roughly**!"*

Idiomatically, it's perfectly normal *in some contexts* to use the imperative *"Quit/Stop [doing something]!"* even *after* the other person has already done whatever you're complaining about. The important thing is there just has to be at least some possibility that they *might do it again*.

In OP's citation, Mrs. Barrows (the speaker) is obviously slightly caught off guard - all she knows is she's just been rudely jostled - *she's not quite sure what's going on* (maybe there might be further roughness).

Another possible context - mother and teenage daughter have just had an argument; daughter flounces out of the house, slamming the front door as she leaves. Mother shouts after her...

> "Quit slamming the door!"

To "explain" that one you have to assume the mother is to at least some degree railing against her daughter's *habitual* behaviour (if she's done it before, she might be going to do it again *at some time*).